# Get phone number from simslot 1 and simslot 2 in android using xamarin/c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using xamarin. I want to get phone numbers from dual sim phone using c#. I've found some java code but i need the c# code.

Comment: Should be fairly simple to convert the Java code to C#. Any particular area you are tuck on? Maybe provide the code and specific questions?

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/12/how-to-get-phone-number-programmatically-in-android.html

Comment: Which part of the conversion demo Java to C# are you having problems with?

Comment: private String getMyPhoneNO() {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        return mPhoneNumber;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to translate, you just need to get used to the differences between Java and the C# wrappers. C# will use properties instead of getXXX methods, and use CamelCase instead of all caps.

Inside your activity class:

```
using Android.Telephony;

public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    private string GetMyPhoneNumber() 
    { 
        var tMgr = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
        return tMgr.Line1Number; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get number 2 from dual sim.

Comment: I'm sure you can work out how to do it. Have you tried to code I've already provided and played with it?